# how to mock dependency in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am new to python unit testing framework and lot of confusion in mocking dependency.

I am trying to write unit tests for below member function of a class, (`check_something()`):

```
class Validations:    
    def check_something(self):
        abc = os.environ['PLATFORM']
        xyz = Node()
        no_of_nodes = len(xyz.some_type_var)
        if abc != "X_PLATFORM" or no_of_nodes != 1:
            raise someException()
```

How do we eliminate dependency ?

1. Need to mock `Node()` ?
2. How do we make sure `abc` is assigned with `X_PLATFORM` ?
3. How to assign value `1` to variable `no_of_nodes`? which is in turn derived from `Node()` object.

   ```
   class Node(object):
       def __init__(self):
           self.nodes = DEF()
           self.some_type_var = someclass().getType()
           self.localnode = os.environ['HOSTNAME']
           self.peertype = self.get_peer_type()

       def get_peer_type(self):
           return node
   ```

I tried writing below unit test. I am unable to check for fail and pass condition. I am not sure whether it is correct or not.

```
class TestValidation(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch.object(Node, "get_peer_type")
    @mock.patch('somefile.Node', spec=True)
    def test_1(self, mock_object1, mock_object2):
        os.environ['PLATFORM'] = 'X_PLATFORM'
        obj = Validations()
        self.assertRaises(someException, obj.check_something)
```

Validation class uses `Node()` Class object and Node class uses some other class.

1. How to make sure exception is raised or not depending on the condition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you'd mock anything external to the unit of code under test. Here that means the `os.environ` dictionary and the `Node()` class.

The patch needs to be applied to the module your code is in; `@mock.patch('somefile.Node', spec=True)` is correct if `somefile` is the same module as `Validations`; see the [*Where to patch* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) as to why that is.

I'm not sure that using `spec=True` is all that helpful here; your `Node` attributes are all instance attributes created in `Node.__init__`, so they are not available on the *class*, which is what informs the spec. See the section on [autospeccing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#auto-speccing) on how to overcome that if you really want to set a spec.

`abc` is set from `os.environ`, you can use the [`patch.dict()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch.dict) to patch that dictionary for your needs.

The `xyz = len(xyz.some_type_var)` is simply handled by either setting the `some_type_var` attribute to an object with the right length, *or* by setting `xyz.some_type_var.__len__.return_value`, since it is the `xyz.some_type_var.__len__()` method that is called for the `len()` function.

So, to test, you'd do:

```
class TestValidation(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('somefile.Node')
    def test_1(self, mock_node):
        # set up the Node() instance, with the correct length
        node_instance = mock_node.return_value
        node_instance.some_type_var.__len__ = 2
        # or, alternatively, node_instance.some_type_var = (1, 2)

        # set up os.environ['PLATFORM']
        with mock.patch.dict('os.environ', PLATFORM='X_PLATFORM'):
            obj = Validations()
            with self.assertRaises(someException):
                obj.check_something()
```