# Python unittest with external depenincies

Tags: python, unit-testing

So I am confused how the mocking stuff works. patch in particular with external dependencies. So far I have seen examples like this one [how to mock dependency in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32672906/how-to-mock-dependency-in-python) where it shows how to mock out one of your own objects, but then uses things like "with mock.patch.dict('os.environ', PLATFORM='X_PLATFORM'):" to mock out the os.environ.

I have also seen examples like this [How to do unit testing of functions writing files using python unittest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942820/how-to-do-unit-testing-of-functions-writing-files-using-python-unittest) where they are using mock_open to mock os.open. But none of this seems to fit what I need.

Lets say you have a function as follows

```
import tensorflow as tf

def load_model(self, model_path=None):
    if model_path is None:
        model_path = self.model_path
    graph_def = None
    with tf.gfile.GFile(model_path, "rb") as file_handle:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef.FromString(file_handle.read())
    if graph_def is None:
        print('Cannot find inference graph in tar archive.')
        raise
    try:
        with self.graph.as_default() as self.graph:
            tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
    except Exception as error:
        print(str(error))
        raise
    self.session = tf.Session(graph=self.graph)

    return True
```

How do you mock out all the tensorflow functions? I want to mock what the file_handle.read() call returns so I can control what is sent into the tf.GraphDef.FromString function, which I also want to mock. I just want some asserts that tell me if these functions are called with the data I feed it. If I control what FromString returns, that controls what goes into the tf.import_graph_def call as well. So I want to mock that as well and assert that it is called with the proper data as well. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently this is how you do it! Anyone else know of a better/cleaner way?

```
    def test_load_model_none_model_path_2(self):
    with mock.patch.object(tf, 'import_graph_def', return_value='import success') as mock_import_graph_def_method:
        with mock.patch.object(tf.GraphDef, 'FromString', return_value='some string') as mock_from_string_method:
            with mock.patch.object(tf.gfile.GFile, 'read', return_value='some data') as mock_read_method:

                load_model_return = self.engine.load_model()

                mock_read_method.assert_called()
                mock_from_string_method.assert_called_once_with(
                    'some data')
                mock_import_graph_def_method.assert_called_once_with(
                    'some string', name='')
```